# Проблема с batch

Tags: bat, переменные

Если я создаю 3 или больше переменных, то batch-файл запускается и исчезает, причём, когда есть только 2 переменных, всё работает

Рабочий файл:

```
@echo off
title timer
echo 2 ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ - минуты и секунды
pause
goto main
set /a s= 0
set /a m= 0
:main
timeout 1 >nul
set /a s= %s% + 1
if %s%==60 (
    set /a m= %m% + 1
    set /a s= 0
)
cls
echo %s%
echo %m%
goto main
```

Нерабочий файл:

```
@echo off
title timer
echo 3 ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ - часы, минуты и секунды
pause
goto main
set /a s= 0
set /a m= 0
set /a h=0
:main
timeout 1 >nul
set /a s= %s% + 1
if %s%==60 (
    set /a m= %m% + 1
    set /a s= 0
)
if %m%==60 (
    set /a h= %h% + 1
    set /a m= 0
)
cls
echo %s%
echo %m%
echo %h%
goto main
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что в структуре сравнения **IF** и в блоке исполнения нескольких команд **()** переменные могут считаются частью кода.
Рекомендую однотипные операции присвоения исполнять как одну.
То есть следующие строки превращаются в одну.

```
if %s%==60 (
    set /a m= %m% + 1
    set /a s= 0
)
```

Стало

```
if %s%==60 @set /a "m=%m%+1, s=0"
```

Во вторых, в операции сравнения значения переменных лучше взять в двойные кавычки, чтобы избежать проблем. Т.е. операция сравнения минут следует превратить в строковое сравнение,записывается так:

```
if "%m%"=="60" set /a h=%h%+1, m=0
```

И в пятой строке рекомендую избавиться от команды перехода **goto**, иначе не инициализируются основные переменные **s,h,m**.

Если хотите сохранить собственную структуру кода и не заморачиваться с переменными. Есть альтернативное решение, используйте **расширенную обработку команд**:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

[partness](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2524009/error-running-command-shell-scripts-that-include-parentheses)